# Inserting data works, but cannot retrieve it from MongoDB using YiiMongoDB Suite

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, yii-extensions

*First off I know the developer stopped working on this extension full time, but from what I understand there are still alot of people using it. Hoping someone can help me with this (hopefully simple problem!)*

I'm trying to read the data I just inserted into MongoDB using the YiiMongoDbSuite extension.

The data is successfully inserted as I can see it via the mongo console.

The problem is when I try to retrieve it. Here's the code I'm running together - it inserts it (no problem), but can't retrieve it:

```
<?php

$new = new Character();
$new->playerName = "Yii-Insert-Test";
$new->playerId = "123456789";
$new->playerScore = "9001";
$new->save();

$findAll = Character::model()->findAll();
foreach($findAll as $result) {
echo $result->playerName; // result should be "Yii-Insert-Test", instead it's NULL
}

?>
```

It does get inserted though:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54a0deda60fc21843100002a"),
"playerName" : "Yii-Insert-Test",
"playerId" : "123456789",
"playerScore" : "9001"
}
```

And here's my very simple model Character.php :

```
<?php

class Character extends EMongoDocument
{

public $_id;
public $playerName;
public $playerId;
public $playerScore;


public function getCollectionName()
{
    return 'usercollection';
}

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('playerName', 'required'),
    );
}

public function attributeNames()
{
    return array(
        'playerName' => 'Character Name',
        'playerId' => 'Character ID',
        'playerScore' => 'Character Score',
    );
}

public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
  {
    return parent::model($className);
  }
}
```

I feel like it's right in front of me but can't see what the problem is.

### edit:

slowly figuring it out - looks like I am receiving data, but it's all empty - this is the mongoDB cursor. I'm already doing a forloop to iterate it, so I'll have to figure out what else I'm **not** doing.

Comment: YiiMongoDBSuite was last updated 4 years ago (2010), which was around the time of MongoDB 1.4/1.6 (for context, the current MongoDB server version is 2.6 and 2.8 RCs are out). This extension has obvious bugs & limitations that will slow down your development (for example: lack of support for building `$or` queries, uses older API for PHP driver, has assumptions that `_id`s will always be ObjectIds, ...). I would **strongly** encourage you upgrade to the latest version of Yii2 which [includes MongoDB support](http://www.yiiframework.com/news/81/yii-2-0-0-is-released/).

Comment: Thank you Stennie. I did not realize that it has been 4 years (time flies). I'll move on to Yii 2.